# domXpath - get the class after an ID

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

I have the following HTML:

```
<p id="v1"><span class="verseref">1</span>Verse 1</p>
<div class="admonition">
<p class="first admonition-title">Title Here</p>
Foo Bar
</div>
<p id="v2"><span class="verseref">2</span>Verse 2</p>
<div class="admonition">
<p class="first admonition-title">Title Here</p>
Bar Foo
</div>
```

And I need to get the data 'Bar Foo'.  How can I do this?  The class 'admonition' is ambiguous .  I need to be able to reference `p#id 1`, then the **next** `div.admonition`.

Is this possible with domXpath? (Using PHP?) and if so, what query would I run to get that?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.getnodepath.php this may be helpful

Comment: @FDL no, I have no idea where to start.  The best I can manage is to get a successful query for the p#id: `//div[@id='v1']`

Comment: `//p[@class="first admonition-title']/following-sibling::text()`?

Comment: @MarcB What would go in text() ?

Comment: you only want the `Bar foo` in the v2? or `Foo bar` in v1 as well?

Comment: @MarcB Sorry I should explain.  I have multiple documents with the structure above.  I need to grab each text within `p.first admonition-title` and label it with the number contained in p#id.  So I need a way to grab each individually.

Comment: xpath queries can be restricted to particular dom tree branches. run one query to get all of the p#id nodes, then loop on those results to get the sibling p.first nodes, e.g. `->query('//following-sibling:p[@class=...]/next-sibling::text()', $p_with_id_node_from_previous_query)`

Comment: @MarcB can you put that written out full in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get "bar foo"..
Try this..
After initializing xpath..

```
$idV2 = $xpath->query('//p[@id=v2]')->item(0);
$admonition = $idV2->nextSibling;
$children = $admonition->childNodes;
$BarFoo = $children->item(1)->nodeValue;
echo $BarFoo;
```